# how to append data/results to the beginning of a spreadsheet , every time you run a python script

Tags: python, google-sheets, append, google-app-engine-python

I want to append the results from my script to the beginning of the spreadsheet every time I run the script. Data should not get appended to the end of every column, but it should get appended to the top of the column/beginning of the spreadsheet.

```
rangeName = sheet_name + '!A1:A'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You'll find users more willing/able to help if you include the piece of code you're having trouble with and what you've tried so far. Please include a [Minimal, Complete Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Another useful link: [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You could show us the script maybe?

Comment: I think the easiest way may be to ensure you are also including timestamps in your data rows that are being appended, and then sort by the timestamp column to get the newest timestamps to the top.

Comment: Do u want the whole code ? i didnt know how to try this: I think the easiest way may be to ensure you are also including timestamps in your data rows that are being appended, and then sort by the timestamp column to get the newest timestamps to the top